# Meizu Pro 5 ota 11 and ota 12 bluetooth problems

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bluetooth

I have problems with bluetooth. When I connect my Jabra Supreme headset, or connect with my car (Ford Fiesta), I only hear a lot of noise.
This is both when I make a call, or receive an incoming call.
I can hear music via bluetooth without problems on both headset, and in the car.

Comment: Are you sure the issue appeared after this update? There were bugs related to bluetooth connections (with cars and other) already reported after previous updates.

Comment: The problem relates to my new Meizu pro 5. I have no problems with my BQ Aquaris E4.5 . Both of them are on OTA 11.

Comment: I've the same on meizu pro 5, not on nexus 4
Did you fill a bug already about that on launchpad ?

Comment: Here there is : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1590844

Comment: Now I have made a bug report. Hope this will be fixed very soon. I can't use the phone in my daily work until it is possible to use bluetooth connection.

Comment: After OTA 12 still the same problem! There is a lot of noise when I answer, or make a call. It is impossible to hear anything. Am I the only one with this problem!?

Comment: Now my BQ Aquaris E4.5 has the same problem after OTA 12.